# Removing values form a list in pandas dataframe column based on another list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have a column in a dataframe which contains lists. I want to be able to remove elements from these lists based on elements that I have in another list (as shown below).

I tried to use list comprehension but it seems to give no result.

```
import pandas as pd

sys_list = ['sys1', 'sys2', 'sys3']
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[['sys1', 'sys2', 'user1'], 
                        ['user3', 'user6', 'user1'], 
                        ['sys1', 'sys2', 'sys3']]})

df['A'] = [item for item in df['A'] if item not in sys_list]

print(df)

                       A
0    [sys1, sys2, user1]
1  [user3, user6, user1]
2     [sys1, sys2, sys3]
```

I need to achieve this:

```
                       A
0                [user1]
1  [user3, user6, user1]
2                     []
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in set(sys_list)])
print (df)
                       A                      B
0    [sys1, sys2, user1]                [user1]
1  [user3, user6, user1]  [user3, user6, user1]
2     [sys1, sys2, sys3]                     []
```

Or similar list comprehension like deleted answer:

```
df['B'] = [[item for item in l if item not in set(sys_list)] for l in df['A']]
```

Or solution with `set`s with [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference):

```
df['B'] = df['A'].map(set(sys_list).difference).map(list)
```

Comment: Surprisingly `.map(set(sys_list).difference)` performs slightly better. I would have expected both approaches to perform just as well

Comment: Thank you! It worked on a sample that I had provided. However, when I apply any of these solutions to my actual df I get "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable". I have checked values and all of them are strings so I am super puzzled whit this...

Comment: @kajnwunda - I think there should be missing values, is possible remove them before by `df = df.dropna(subset=['A'])` ?

Answer (score 2):

You may use `sets` for a better performance (this approach assumes that the order within the lists is not important, as it will change):

```
sys_set = set(['sys1', 'sys2', 'sys3'])

df['A'] = (df.A.map(set)-sys_set).map(list)
```

---

```
print(df)
                    A
0                [user1]
1  [user6, user1, user3]
2                     []
```

Answer (score 1):

with `apply`:

```
df.A.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i not in sys_list])
```

---

```
0                  [user1]
1    [user3, user6, user1]
2                       []
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych " `[[item for item in l if item not in sys_list] for l in df['A']]` also works , please dont delete